# Simplified Version of IPA?

Tags: phonology, writing-systems

In [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet), the sounds of many symbols are so close that they are indistinguishable to me! For example, [bʊk], [ɓʊk], or [βʊk]. Even though they *do* have some minor differences, but all a listener like me hears is "book".

So is there any "Simplified IPA" where they contain all possible pronunciations but yet omit all those phonetically indistinguishable symbols?

Comment: They're not indistinguishable at all, and anyone trying to learn a language which distinguishes them will either learn them or never acquire the language to any fluency.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason that all the different characters for “the same sound” exist is because they’re *not* the same sound, and trained linguists/linguistic researchers *can* hear the difference. Any “simplified IPA” wouldn’t be a true “IPA”, and would not be able to accurately represent the difference in sounds; you would end up with the present situation where the spelling of words in a language not suited for the alphabet being used does not accurately reflect the actual pronunciation of the word (for example, Spanish *vaca*, cow, which some people hear as though it should be spelled *baka*, because neither ***b*** nor ***v*** in the Latin alphabet is an accurate representation of the sound used).

Comment: I totally understand, but is there any system for the "regular people" (not trained linguists/linguistic researchers)!? Because some differences in IPA are truly "too minute"! One really could never tell the difference "without training"!

Comment: Any system for the "regular people" wouldn't be "universal" in the sense that IPA is; you'd simply end up with Yet Another Not-Quite-Accurate Transliteration Convention. You might as well pick a dictionary that doesn't use IPA (virtually any dictionary aimed at users below the collegiate level would be a good candidate) and adopt its system for representing pronunciations.

Comment: Another possible source for an alternative pronunciation representation system might be to look at phonetically-based systems for teaching children to read, such as [DISTAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_instruction) or the Pitman Initial Teaching Alphabet [[Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_Teaching_Alphabet)] [[Omniglot link](https://www.omniglot.com/writing/ita.htm)], or any of the [alternative systems listed on Omniglot](https://www.omniglot.com/writing/alternative.htm) under the headings "Alternative spelling/writing systems" or "Phonetic Alphabets".

Comment: OK. Is there any statistic research on the IPA usages!? Maybe I could pick some "most often used" alphabets for my language.

Comment: If you're looking for a transcription system for a conlang that you're creating, just make one up using whatever alphabet (or subset thereof) you're comfortable with, and which distinguishes between the various sounds of _your_ conlang. For example, if your conlang has the sound represented in IPA by ***[β]*** but not the ones represented by ***[b]*** or ***[ɓ]***, there's no real reason not to use the glyph ***b*** to represent it, if that makes it easier to write out the language or to document it.

Comment: THAT is the problem! I wish to create a language that "contains" all possible pronunciations, but not SO minute! Imagine I create 3 "different" words with [bʊk], [ɓʊk], and [βʊk], my user WILL think "WTF IS YOUR PROBLEM!?". THAT'S why I try to omit those alphabets that could be "considered the same".

Comment: If the language contains _all_ possible pronunciations, then the full IPA is the only possible solution. If you don't want to deal with the minute differences between e.g. [β], [b], and  [ɓ], then your language doesn't actually contain all possible pronunciations, and you can simply choose one of the alternatives to represent whichever sound your language _does_ have.

Comment: OK, let me ponder over your comment and see what I can come up with. Thanks!

Comment: @PiggyChu001 PHOIBLE has the most common segments cross-linguistically: https://phoible.org/parameters

Answer (score 18):

If you're notating a language that uses [β] or [ɓ] *but does not distinguish it* from [b], that is, if there are no words such that changing one of these consonants to the other changes the meaning of the word (perhaps because [β] occurs only between vowels and [b] elsewhere), then for most purposes you write them all as /b/; so that is a “simplified IPA”.  This is called **broad** transcription, written with slashes to distinguish it from **narrow** transcription using brackets.  A famous example: English /p/ includes both [p] and [pʰ], which are distinguished in many languages including Zulu, Hindustani, Mandarin.

No language makes phonemic distinctions between *all* pairs of phones represented by distinct symbols in IPA; but every symbol exists because *some* language contrasts it with others.

Answer (score -2):

There is SaypU, which tries to creates a universal phonetic alphabet for all languages with only 24 letters, many of which can be used to represent slightly different sounds in different languages.

"a" in SaypU can represent /a/, /æ/, and /ɑ/, depending on the language. "y" represents /j/, /ʎ/, and /ʝ/. "w" represents both /w/ and /ɥ/.

Comment: I’m not entirely sure this qualifies as a ‘universal phonetic alphabet’ by any means. What happens, for instance, in a language which distinguishes /a æ ɑ/ (e.g. Äiwoo), /j ʎ/ (e.g. Warlpiri, some Spanish dialects), or /w ɥ/ (e.g. French, Abkhaz)?

Comment: @bradrn, you use diacritics (a, ä, ã).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Do the diacritics have any consistent meaning within SaypU, or are they used in an ad-hoc fashion? I’d call it a ‘universal phonetic alphabet for all languages’ in the former case only.

Comment: @bradrn, They don’t have any consistent meaning.

Comment: In that case, I wouldn’t call it a ’universal phonetic alphabet’, since it can’t specify the exact phonetic details of every sound in the same way IPA can. If anything, I’d say it’s a standardised set of mappings for romanization purposes, similarly to e.g. the [General Alphabet of Cameroon Languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Alphabet_of_Cameroon_Languages).